# The workflows in workbox only appear in master database

Tags: workflow

I am using sitecore 9.3, i have created a database that is cloned from the web database and i need to check if an item can be assigned to workflow in this database and then upon approval it can be published to web database, or this scenario is applicable only in master database

Comment: Workflows are a very old part of Sitecore and haven't seen any significant updates since v6.3 when I first saw it. I wouldn't be surprised if there was a "master" hard-coded in there somewhere and it simply won't work against a different database, but theoretically it should be possible.

Comment: You need to enable workflows for your new database.

Comment: I handled it from the configuration of the database in config file.

Comment: Please use upvotes and tick answers, instead of appreciation comments. Helps the site, helps SEO.

Comment: I replied and already used the flag comment before you add the final answer already. as well i have ticked the answer you added and the upvotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cloned your database from "web", I assume you also cloned your `<database>` definition from web. That one does not have workflows enabled.

You need to add various systems to the cloned database, for workflows to work.

```
    <database id="master" singleInstance="true" type="Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel" role:require="Standalone or Reporting or Processing or ContentManagement">
      <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
      <icon>Images/database_master.png</icon>
      <dataProviders hint="list:AddDataProvider">
        <dataProvider ref="dataProviders/main" param1="$(id)">
          <prefetch hint="raw:AddPrefetch">
            <sc.include file="/App_Config/Prefetch/Common.config" />
            <sc.include file="/App_Config/Prefetch/Master.config" />
          </prefetch>
        </dataProvider>
      </dataProviders>
      <securityEnabled>true</securityEnabled>
      <publishVirtualItems>true</publishVirtualItems>
      <PropertyStore ref="PropertyStoreProvider/store[@name='$(id)']" />
      <remoteEvents.EventQueue>
        <obj ref="eventing/eventQueueProvider/eventQueue[@name='$(id)']" />
      </remoteEvents.EventQueue>
      <workflowProvider hint="defer" type="Sitecore.Workflows.Simple.WorkflowProvider, Sitecore.Kernel">
        <param desc="database">$(id)</param>
        <param desc="history store" ref="workflowHistoryStores/main" param1="$(id)" />
      </workflowProvider>
      <archives hint="raw:AddArchive">
        <archive name="archive" />
        <archive name="recyclebin" />
      </archives>
      <NotificationProvider type="Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.$(database).$(database)NotificationProvider, Sitecore.Kernel">
        <param connectionStringName="$(id)">
        </param>
        <param desc="databaseName">$(id)</param>
      </NotificationProvider>
      <cacheSizes hint="setting">
        <data>100MB</data>
        <items>50MB</items>
        <paths>2500KB</paths>
        <itempaths>50MB</itempaths>
        <standardValues>2500KB</standardValues>
      </cacheSizes>
    </database>
```

Specifically, these are critical.

```
      <workflowProvider hint="defer" type="Sitecore.Workflows.Simple.WorkflowProvider, Sitecore.Kernel">
        <param desc="database">$(id)</param>
        <param desc="history store" ref="workflowHistoryStores/main" param1="$(id)" />
      </workflowProvider>
      <archives hint="raw:AddArchive">
        <archive name="archive" />
        <archive name="recyclebin" />
      </archives>
      <NotificationProvider type="Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.$(database).$(database)NotificationProvider, Sitecore.Kernel">
        <param connectionStringName="$(id)">
        </param>
        <param desc="databaseName">$(id)</param>
      </NotificationProvider>
```